# How to force a multiindex pandas dataframe to have the same number of index in a level?

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
Level0     Level1     Value

Cat1       Subcat1    1
           Subcat2    2
           Subcat3    3

Cat2       Subcat1    4
           Subcat3    5

Cat3       Subcat1    6
           Subcat2    7
           Subcat3    8
```

In `Cat2` I have only `Subcat1` and `Subcat3`. What I would like to do is `Cat2` to have also `Subcat2` and set its `Value` to zero:

```
Level0     Level1     Value

Cat1       Subcat1    1
           Subcat2    2
           Subcat3    3

Cat2       Subcat1    4
           Subcat2    0
           Subcat3    5

Cat3       Subcat1    6
           Subcat2    7
           Subcat3    8
```

I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `pandas.MultiIndex.from_product`

```
new = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    df.index.levels, names=df.index.names
)

df.reindex(new, fill_value=0)

               Value
Level0 Level1       
Cat1   Subcat1     1
       Subcat2     2
       Subcat3     3
Cat2   Subcat1     4
       Subcat2     0
       Subcat3     5
Cat3   Subcat1     6
       Subcat2     7
       Subcat3     8
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do `stack` and `unstack`

```
df.unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
```